# Set contains only the zero vector

Tags: linear-algebra

A finite set $S = \{x_1, x_2, \dots , x_m\}$ of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is said to be linearly dependent if there exist scalars (real numbers) $c_1, c_2, \dots , c_m$, not all of which are $0$, such that
$c_1x_1 + c_2x_2 + \dots + c_nx_n = 0$ 
(see http://www.math.ku.edu/~lerner/m291F08/Chapter11.pdf)

Let $ S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be the set whose only element is the zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. That is $ S=\{[0\ \dots 0]^T\}$. Is $S$ linearly dependent? How?

Comment: It shouldn't be. After all, every linear combination of the element $0$ is  zero, so for example $1 \cdot 0 = 0$, hence the set is  not linearly independent. In fact, no set containing zero can be linearly independent for this reason.

Comment: Nothing changes S consists only one vector ? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You are welcome. And $S$ is linearly dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_1$ be the zero vector; choose $c_1=1$. Then $c_1x_1=0$ and $c_1\ne0$. Therefore $S=\{0\}$ is linearly dependent.

You can do similarly whenever $0\in S$: use the coefficient $1$ for the zero vector and the coefficient $0$ for all other vectors in $S$.

---

Note that, by convention, a summation with just one summand is that single object (number, vector, or whatever you're summing up). Similarly, by convention, a summation with *no* summand is zero (number, vector, or whatever you're summing up).

Thus the empty set is linearly independent: you can't find zero coefficients to place in an empty linear combination of vectors, can you?